# Getting past a protocol mismatch after a Telnet connection

Tags: ssh, cmd, telnet, openssh, remote-connection

This is what shows up:         ssh-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2

I am not entirely sure what this means. It occurs when I am trying to remotely connect to my mac from a different windows computer using telnet. What does it mean and what do I do to get past it? Do I type the password of the computer? I only get to type one line before it says

"Protocol mismatch.

Connection to host lost."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be connecting to a ssh port by telnet.
They are different protocols.
try

```
ssh [HOST]
```

instead of

```
telnet [HOST] 22
```

.